# Comparing two lists and syncronizing the database based on differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following resource relationship:

```
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :track_courses
  has_many :tracks, through: :track_courses
end
```

as well as a mirroring relationship inside the Track model. The TrackCourse table which connects these models has these rows:

> **id:** primary key
>
> **track_id:** represents the track
>
> **course_id:** represents the course
>
> **position:** the ordering of the course inside that track

I want to allow admin users to be able to update the courses in each track via ajax. I have a list on the front-end that is being passed to the controller as a hash:

```
front_end_list = { course_id => position }
```

which represents the object and its position on the front-end sortable.

I'm also looking up the list of existing courses in that track:

```
existing_courses = TrackCourse.where("track_id = ?", track_id).all
```

**GOAL:** Compare these two lists and syncronize the database entries according to the front-end list. Essentially, if the user inserts Course 15 into position 2 on the webpage, I need to either insert that entry into TrackCourse table (if it doesn't exist) or update its position (if it exists). And vice versa for remove.

What is the best way of doing this? Do ActiveRecord/ActiveRelation provide methods for it? Or do I have to write something myself?

**UPDATE:** I found a gem called [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list), but it seems to be designed for ActiveRecord tables as opposed to ActiveRelation. It essentially expects position values to be unique, whereas in TrackCourse there can be multiple course with same position (in different tracks).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I'll post my code here in case it helps anyone else down the line.

I have this method in my controller that processes the ajax request from the front-end:

```
def sort
    track_id = params[:track_id]

    courses_in_list = {}
    params[:course].each do |courseid|
        position = params[:course].index(courseid)
        courses_in_list[courseid.to_i] = position
    end

    existing_courses_in_track = {}
    TrackCourse.where("track_id = ?", track_id).to_a.each do |track_course|
        existing_courses_in_track[track_course.course_id] = track_course.position
    end

    if courses_in_list.length < existing_courses_in_track.length

        existing_courses_in_track.each do |courseid, position|

            if courses_in_list[courseid].nil?
                track_course = TrackCourse.where(track_id: track_id, course_id: courseid).first
                track_course.remove_from_list
                track_course.destroy!
            end

        end

    else

        if existing_courses_in_track.empty?
            track_course = TrackCourse.new(track_id: track_id, 
                                           course_id: courses_in_list.keys[0])
            track_course.insert_at(courses_in_list.values[0])
            p "first track!"

        else
            courses_in_list.each do |courseid, position|

                track_exists = false
                if !existing_courses_in_track[courseid].nil?
                    track_course_position = existing_courses_in_track[courseid]
                    track_exists = true
                end

                if !track_exists
                    TrackCourse.new(track_id: track_id, course_id: courseid).insert_at(position)
                else
                    p "else statement"
                    track_course = TrackCourse.where(track_id: track_id, course_id: courseid).first
                    track_course.update_attribute(:position, position)
                end
            end
        end
    end
    render :nothing => true
end
```

Essentially, I'm building two hashes, one based on the list of front-end items and their position, and one based on the database courses and their position. I then compare them. If the front-end list is shorter, that means the user removed an item, so I iterate through the backend list, find the extra item, and remove it. Then I employ a similar mechanism for adding items to the list and resorting the list. The [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem really helps with keeping things in the correct position. However, I did have to limit its scope when I included it in my model to ensure it runs only on relationships (TrackCourses) with a specific track_id.